# Can data loaded in as newAPIHadoopRDD be converted into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-bigquery, pyspark

I'm using PySpark to load data from Google BigQuery.

I've loaded data by using:

```
dfRates = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)
```

Where conf is defined as https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example.

I need this data as a DataFrame, so I tried,

```
row = Row(['userId','accoId','rating']) # or row = Row(('userId','accoId','rating'))
dataRDD = dfRates.map(row).toDF()
```

and

```
dataRDD = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dfRates,['userId','accoId','rating'])
```

But it does not convert the data into a DataFrame. Is there a way to convert it into a DataFrame?

Comment: Did you figure out what the best way is to import a BQ table as a PySpark DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the types can represented using Spark SQL types there is no reason it couldn't be. The only problem here seems to be your code.

`newAPIHadoopRDD` returns a RDD of pairs (tuple of length equal two). In this particular context it looks you'll get `(int, str)` in Python which clearly cannot be unpacked into `['userId','accoId','rating']`.

According to the doc you've linked `com.google.gson.JsonObject` is represented as a JSON string which can be either parsed on a Python side using standard Python utils (`json` module):

```
def parse(v, fields=["userId", "accoId", "rating"]):
    row = Row(*fields)
    try:
        parsed = json.loads(v)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        parsed = {}
    return row(*[parsed.get(x) for x in fields])

dfRates.map(parse).toDF()
```

or on the Scala / `DataFrame` side using `get_json_object`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, get_json_object

dfRates.toDF(["id", "json_string"]).select(
  # This assumes you expect userId field
  get_json_object(col("json_string"), "$.userId"), 
  ...
)
```

Please note the differences in the syntax I've used to define and create rows.

Comment: If the field names of the dataset are not known to me, or are too many to list in the code, is there a way to execute this method?

Answer (score 0):

hbase table rows:

```
hbase(main):008:0> scan 'test_hbase_table'
ROW                                            COLUMN+CELL
 dalin                                         column=cf:age, timestamp=1464101679601, value=40
 tangtang                                      column=cf:age, timestamp=1464101649704, value=9
 tangtang                                      column=cf:name, timestamp=1464108263191, value=zitang
2 row(s) in 0.0170 seconds
```

here we go

```
import json
host = '172.23.18.139'
table = 'test_hbase_table'
conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "zookeeper.znode.parent": "/hbase-unsecure", "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": table}
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"
hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
        keyConverter=keyConv,
        valueConverter=valueConv,
        conf=conf)
hbase_rdd1 = hbase_rdd.flatMapValues(lambda v: v.split("\n"))
```

and here we got the results

```
tt=sqlContext.jsonRDD(hbase_rdd1.values())
In [113]: tt.show()
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----+------+
|columnFamily|qualifier|     row|    timestamp|type| value|
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----+------+
|          cf|      age|   dalin|1464101679601| Put|    40|
|          cf|      age|tangtang|1464101649704| Put|     9|
|          cf|     name|tangtang|1464108263191| Put|zitang|
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----+------+
```

Comment: i am getting this error Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat